# "No changes to display" when changes are apparent

Tags: feature-request, review, revisions-list

As a result of a revision to an already-closed question, it showed up in the [re-open review queue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/34502). Clicking to see what the revision (edit) was, the result was "No changes to display":

[image]

Viewing the [full revision history](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/155073/revisions) revealed the change to be fairly minimal (spelling + capitalization). The question was fairly new/recent and therefore the edit was not a problem:

[image]

It seems like the revision check is case insensitive in terms of the question body (tikz's ~ TikZ's) yet does not show any changes in the title. Sometimes a major title revision makes the question far more useful and searchable (for example, "Help solve this error" compared to "Incompatibility between package X and Y"), and this should be apparent in a review queue without having to view the revision history.

Comment: According to the [timeline](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/155073/timeline), the edit was made five seconds after the post was closed. That might be close enough to confuse the review interface. Still sounds like a (minor) bug, though.